# making my C code shorter

Tags: c

I made a program that calculates the equation ( gives me the values x1 and x2 ). But the problem is though , i needed to write 2 seperate functions for x1 and x2 , even though i only needed to change a "+" sign to a "-" sign to get x2. Is it possible to get the same output put only using one function ? Heres the code :

```
double equation(double a, double b, double c) {
    double argument, x1;
    argument = sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);
    x1 = ( -b + argument ) / (2 * a);
    return x1;
}

double equation2(double a, double b, double c) {
    double argument, x2;
    argument = sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);
    x2 = ( -b - argument ) / (2 * a); // here i changed the "+" sign to "-"
    return x2;
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You can post as often as you please, so long as you aren't posting duplicates.

Comment: This site has ~9 million posts, I don't think that anyone will mind if you post even one question each hour (as long as they are *good* questions) :)

Comment: Actually, it is *beneficial* to the site to have as many questions/answers as possible as long as they all have value.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your actual question, but note that `b*b` is almost always better than `pow(b,2)`. (Possible exception: if instead of `b` you have some long complicated expression.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres a couple different ways you can do this.  Gareth mentions one, but another is to use output parameters.

Using pointers as input parameters, you can populate them both in one function, and you don't need to return anything

```
void equation(double a, double b, double c, double *x1, double *x2) {
    double argument, x1;
    argument = sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);
    *x1 = ( -b + argument ) / (2 * a);
    *x2 = ( -b - argument ) / (2 * a);
}
```

Then call it from your main code:

```
int main (void )
{
    //Same up to the prints above
    double x1, x2;
    equation ( a , b, c , &x1, &x2);

    printf("\nx1 = %.2f", x1);
    printf("\nx2 = %.2f", x2);
}
```

Comment: This is nice, because you save yourself from performing the expensive square-root twice. You could even store `b/(2*a)` separately, too. This is also a good candidate for inlining.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to mention that you can simplify a little further as well

Comment: Thank you, I get it now ( I think , even though i really haven't learned about pointers yet ) :D .
Finally i can go to sleep with my mind calm. Thank you again.

Comment: Pointers can be rather tricky to get the hang of, but they are very powerful tools in the right hands

Answer (score 3):

Pass in another argument that's either +1 or -1, and multiply `argument` by it. Or, pass in another argument that's either 0/false or non-0/true, and add or subtract conditionally (with an `if` statement or a `...?...:...` "ternary operator".

[EDITED to remove a response to part of the original question that's now been removed.]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite follow you, as i've just started out. Could you please write your solution in code if that doesn't bother you much ?

Comment: It's precisely *because* you're new to the game that I don't want to be too explicit at you -- you'll learn better if you do some of the working out for yourself! But *paxdiablo* has posted some code that takes the first of the approaches I mentioned.

Comment: I wouldn't take this option, as it is unnatural to pass in a +1 / -1 to specify which option, and true / false don't map to the two options of the quadratic equation in a meaningful way.  Yes, it works, but you then have to know far too much about the implementation to make it work for any calling code, and the name of the game is to not have your calling code know "inner" details of the methods.  Otherwise, it becomes impossible to disentangle them in the future (a necessary step for changing one, but not the other).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that it's not great style to do this. But, well, the OP asked how to do it and I answered :-). (Sometimes the only good answer to "how do I do X?" is "you don't because it's a really terrible idea". I don't think this one is quite in that category.) Dan F's approach is quite nice.

Comment: A more "idiomatic-C" approach is Dan F.'s solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could* do something like:

```
double equation_either (double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    double argument, x1;
    argument = sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);
    x1 = ( -b + (d * argument)) / (2 * a);
    //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // auto selection of correct sign here
    //
    return x1;
}
:
printf("\nx1 = %.2f", equation_either(a, b, c,  1.0));
printf("\nx2 = %.2f", equation_either(a, b, c, -1.0));
```